# Enrich CSV file with data from database

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I'd like to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, c.created
FROM 'path/to/input.csv' AS csv(id INT, created TIMESTAMP)
JOIN some_table AS t
  ON csv.id = t.id
INTO OUTFILE 'path/to/output.csv'
```

I could only find [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/importing-data-into-mariadb/) which needs `INTO TABLE tbl_name`.

What I'd like to have:

- only SQL
- read-only access to the database
- single statement

Is that possible?

Comment: So what you are looking for is to open up a csv file, select just 2 columns and the result save it into another csv file? With just one statement

Comment: @DavidValladaresL. Yes. I don't see why this shouldn't be possible. But I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Something comes to my mind. I'm not 100% sure that this can be done in one query without making a procedure (that would be just the call of the procedure) but what can be done is: First create a temporary table and load the data in the table with `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Then you can perform a select from that temporary table and save it into the outfile